How to print a string from an index to the end of the string without the use of looping?
Assume a string of "Hello World" and n is an integer representing an index of the string that will be inputted, where n here will be 2.
With the inputted n, I want to print only the string from the n index to the end, which here would be "llo World".
How can I take only the part "llo World" without the use of looping (which is the only solution I can think of)?
More Example:
n = 4
string = "I am sorry"
output: " sorry"

n = 3
string = "I need this"
output: "eed this"
As I said above, I tried to use the method of looping, but I need a more efficient way to execute this which using looping will take way too long for strings with huge sizes.
To summarize my question:
How to print a string from the 'n'th index without the use of looping.
This is how I do it:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::string s;

    std::cin >> n >> s;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << s[i];
    }

    return 0;
}


Use the substring method of string:  s.substr(n);

Ahhh, this is the thing I'm searching for, is there any other way that I am not aware of?

I am not aware of what you are not aware of.  So the answer is:  I don't know, you don't know, we don't know.

You do realise that characters are output (to the console) 1 at a time with synchronization.  So looping in your code would not be a bottleneck.  This feels like either an XY-Problem or Premature Optimization.  Please provide more details of the problem with a [mcve] and an expiation how you would measure a "...a more efficient way ..."

Look at .c_str method and pointer arithmetic.

looping will take way too long for string with huge sizes -- Be aware that substr creates an entirely new string.  You should be considering std::string_view.  Also, how big is "huge"?  Too many new programmers think that a few hundred characters is "huge".  Are you talking about hundreds of thousands of bytes?  Millions of bytes?

how would you use a loop? You do not need a loop here just as you do not need one to print the whole string. I mean no explicit one. Behind the scenes there is a loop, no way to avoid that.

Have you tried printing string + n?

What I usually do with looping is to get the n and loop the printing base from there, I don't necessarily know much about string and how to print this kind of stuff, so saying what I don't know is basically my way of saying 'I don't know any other way other than my way to use looping'. That is why I am asking to find a better solution.

The size of the string could be up to 10^9 in size and it is one of my biggest problem in understanding string in itself. I appreciate all the answers and I will implement what I can accordingly. Have a Good Day everyone.

std::cout << std::string_view{s}.substr(n);

I don't understand.  To process more than one character, there has to be a loop; at least somewhere.

You can use std::string_view to have a view over the original string without modifying it. And then you can adjust that view however you want.
Here's one way of doing it:
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the string (in double quotes) and the index: ";
    std::string str;
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> std::quoted(str) >> n;
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ( n > std::size(str) ) // handling the potential error
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Entered index is greater than the size of the string.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string_view original_view { str };
    std::string_view modified_view { original_view.substr(n) };

    std::cout << "Original string: " << std::quoted(original_view) << '\n'
              << "New string view: " << std::quoted(modified_view) << '\n';
}

For example, enter "Hi, there!" 2 as the input and you'll get ", there!" which is exactly what you want.

@Drew Dormann has already provided the right answer..
In case if you do not want to use STL (std::string) then you can use plain pointer arithmetic.
    #include <iostream>
    int main () {
    char pData[] = "Hello World";
    int n = 6;
    int array_length = sizeof(pData)/sizeof(pData[0])-1;
    if(n < array_length)
    {
       char *pData_from_n_to_end = pData + n;
       std::cout<<pData_from_n_to_end<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"You cannot move past the end of the string";
    }
    
      return 0;
   }


Note that sizeof(pData)/sizeof(pData[0]) in this example will include the null terminator in the array_length, so you should -1 the length. Also, consider using std::size() instead of sizeof.

Hi @Remy Lebeau, Thanks. That makes sense.

You can use the cin.write() method, passing it a char* pointer to the starting character, and the number of characters to write, eg:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::string s;
    
    std::cin >> n >> s;
    
    std::cout.write(s.c_str()+n, s.size()-n); 
    
    return 0;
}

Alternatively, you can use std::string_view, eg:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::string s;
    
    std::cin >> n >> s;

    std::string_view sv = s;
    sv = sv.substr(n);

    // or: std::string_view sv(s.c_str()+n, s.size()-n);
    // or: std::string_view sv(s.begin()+n, s.end());
    
    std::cout << sv; 
    
    return 0;
}


You may add an integer n to a char*.
int main()
{
    auto n = 4;
    auto string = "I am sorry";

    std::cout << string + n;
}

Output
 sorry

